# CSS - select children of a tag until next tag of same type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a following DOM:

```
<div class="someclass">
  <p>
    <p>
      <span></span>
    </p>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to apply a stylesheet to `span` tags which are under the div with `someclass` class, but NOT to `span` tags which are under nested `div`.

There might be any other hierarchy of tags among them and `span` tags might be nested among any tags (except div). And using > will not help.

Can you give me a selector to select them?

Comment: where to post the answer its already been closed

Comment: put your idea to comment

Comment: I think my latest update solves this for you.

Comment: `.someclass p + p span {
 color:#000;
}
.someclass div span {
 color:#f00;
}`

Comment: added another duplicate, you only solution is to consider two selectors. also note that `p` inside `p` is invalid

Comment: @TemaniAfif the tags were just illustrational, you can replace it with section if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use immediate child `>` to accomplish this. You can also use the `*` selector along with negation to accomplish non-div nesting look-ups.

```css
.someclass > p,
.someclass *:not(div) p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">

  <p>Highlight me</p>
  <section><p>Also hightlight me</section>
  <section>
    <section>
      <p>Also hightlight me
    </section>  
  </section>      
  <div>
    <p>Do not highlight me</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not my case ... there might be any hierarchy between div and p tags. > selector is for direct children, but I can have following <div class=""><span><p></p></span> (tag names are just illustrational).

Comment: looks good, but does not work for this case: <div class="someclass">
  <p>
    <span>aa</span>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      <span>aa</span></p>
  </div>
</div> (when element which should not be highlighted is nested in other tags)

Comment: I probably did it: .someclass span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.someclass div span {
  background-color: inherit;
}

Comment: but would be obviously nicer without usage of inherit and using only yellow. Your solution was pretty close but does not count with nested spans.